# ifelse function only returning 0 as result

Tags: if-statement, conditional-statements

I was trying to run this code on R, and it is returning zero values for all my data including those that should not have zero. What could be the problem? Pleas note that I am working with a table

NEW_DAT[, i]<- ifelse((ABC[i:ncol(ABC)])*(1-(XYZ[i:ncol(XYZ)]))-(DEF[i:ncol(DEF)])<0,0,(ABC[i:ncol(ABC)])*(1-(XYZ[i:ncol(XYZ)]))-(DEF[i:ncol(DEF)]))

I was expecting values greater than 0 to be returned while values less than 0 to be turned to zero.